# AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code don't return the entire string

Tags: ios, foundation, pdf417

I'm trying to read a pdf417 code with apple library AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code but this returned me a incomplete chain. For example the result should be:

```
11111111K9190909 MORAL��������������������������������������������������FTV150320A02013100411 ������Ä������PC1‘tw@= Ü·ryÀvxØpuªw{Özwìit¯€znp‡Htg‰wˆæbp¨…€úm ÒŠte„‡õ^p ‚dqw åo\‡ |x’w\U‚½Si¥™|ieS‡› n Oðœ‡ƒSZ› }V‘™ø Kv¢…v¤zÒ§vÚBh©¨ \¤aã– v”¤ú™NíA Áª„fB\ Ÿœ¯‚Xp³éCRŸ¯‹‚‚9y7a¢³‡v6^ ±Yè´ †i»æ»râŠ½t¯Kp½„ä½‡Z=EABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnop
```

but i get only: `11111111K9190909 MORAL`

I think that the middle has another coding(`��������������������������������������������������`) therefore, cut the string and not handing me the rest.

do you know?, if there is any option to hand me the complete code although the middle part is unreadable.

Comment: I dont know about your solution but there is one tutorial which will help you to read pdf file http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-displaying-pdf-documents--mobile-11145

Comment: I speak about PDF417, it is a stacked linear barcode and i try to read with mobile camera. Thanks you anyaway.